# Is it safe to share my itunessConnect App-Specific Shared Secret with my developer?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I am working with an oversea developer who is developing one of my apps.

The app uses a auto-renewable Membership, and he just pointed me out that he needs the App-Specific Shared Secret since his current role and permission (developer & marketer) does not provide him access to it.

I am not sure how I should feel about this or if there wouldn't be a better way for me to proceed, in order for him to finish off the in-app purchases part?

Answer (score 1):

Just send this "App-Specific Shared Secret" if he's working on the In-App Purchase part.  Since this secret code can always regenerate, it safe to send it to him. You still can regenerate it after he finish his part. and you can replace it in his code if you have any worry.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to share your master shared secret you can generate an app-specific shared secret. The developer needs access to a shared secret to securely implement subscriptions. Shared secrets can also be regenerated.

This is what apple recommends:

> The app-specific shared secret is a unique code to receive receipts
>   for only this app’s auto-renewable subscriptions. You may want to use
>   an app-specific shared secret if you’re transferring this app to
>   another developer, or if you want to keep your master shared secret
>   private.

Comment: This is the automatic message on iTunes Connect - Doesn't answer my question.